# How to Hide an Image, if not clicked, in N seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a button that when is clicked, an image  is created using javascript and get prepended to a div (adds it inside a div).

```
var image = new Image();
var imageHtml = image.toHtml();
$('div.board').prepend(imageHtml);

function Image()
{

this.toHtml = function ()
{
return '<img src=\"myImage.png\" width=\"40px\" height=\"40px\" />';
}
}
```

This image can be clicked in 2 seconds then user will have 1 more score and if not clicked in that time, then the image should disappear.

How to do that in javascript?

Thanks,

Comment: That's a strange construct. Also, you don't need to backslash quotations marks of a different kind than the enclosing ones: `'\"' === '"'`. And finally, to solve your problem, set a timeout that you reset every time the image is clicked.

Comment: [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYCxh/) that performs what you need using javascript's `setTimeout` function.  Note that jquery is not required here at all.

Comment: @davin; ah, it doesn't work like c#; thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function start_game(image){
    var timeout = null;
    image.onclick = function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //addScore();
    };
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){  
        image.onclick = null;
        image.style.display = "none";
        // remove the image from dom if needed;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UpNCb/

Comment: thanks; would that be possible to add this functionality inside the Image() class? I mean this to be done before the html image is added on the document then as soon as the image is added to the document (or as soon as ToHtml() method is clicked, this functionality starts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

see [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081119211608AAokDpY), just difference is you going to hide instead of link display

or 
give id 'img_id' to your image

```
function hideimage() {
  document.getElementById('img_id').style.display = 'none';
}

setTimeout(hideimage, 10000);
```

Comment: I hoped I don't have to generate ids for my images.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and the CSS property [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) or [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp).